# Order by date / price

Tags: php

I want to show database records ordered by Datetime or Price when users click on links sort by Datetime or sort by Price. Should I add a condition into the query ?

```js
 $sql = "SELECT p.title AS Title, p.date_published) AS Datetime , p.price   AS Price, c.name AS Category FROM products p

           INNER JOIN categories c
              ON c.id = p.category
           INNER JOIN brands b
              ON b.id = p.brand
              .
              .
              .
    ";

    if (isset($_GET['search'])){

          $locations = array();
          $getters = array();
          $queries = array();

          foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
          .
          .
          .
          }

          if (!empty($brands)) {
            $brd_q = implode(",",$brands);
          }

          if(!empty($getters)) {

            foreach($getters as $key => $value){
              ${$key} = $value;
              switch($key) {
                case 'search':
                array_push($queries, "(p.title LIKE '%$search%' || p.description LIKE '%$search%' || p.number LIKE '%$search%')");
                break;
                case 'scategory':
                array_push($queries, "p.category = $scategory");
                break;
                case 'sbrands':
                array_push($queries, "p_brd.brand_id IN ($brd_q)");
                break;
                .
                .
                .
              }
           }
        }
         
         if(!empty($queries)) {
             $sql .= " WHERE ";
             $i=1;
             foreach($queries as $query) {
                 if ($i < count($queries)) {
                     $sql .= $query." AND ";
                 }else{
                     $sql .= $query;
                 }
                 $i++;
             }

         }
        
          $sql .= " ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
      }
```

Comment: `ORDER By Datetime,Price DESC` didn't work for you?

Comment: What condition? in WHERE?

Comment: Are you know about [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function? I mean `implode(' AND ', $queries)`

Comment: So how do you know which SORT you want to do??

Comment: the condition is when the users click on sort by datetime button they could get the records ordered by Datetime DESC and when they click on sort by Price button they could get the records ordred by Price DESC

Comment: So test that condition and amend `$sql .= " ORDER BY Datetime DESC";` accordingly

Comment: You don't need any SQL "condition", only the apropriate SQL SORT clause. So you would need an `$orderBy = ($_GET['orderBy'] == 'Datetime' ? 'Datetime' : 'Price')` the `$sortOrder = ($_GET['sortOrder'] == 'asc' ? 'ASC' : DESC');` then `$sql .= " ORDER BY $orderBy $sortOrder";`

Comment: then how to show records order by Price If users click on [sort by Price] button ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer

Comment: Be aware, your code is full of SQL injections...

Comment: good morning/afernoon vp_arth I added intval to this block for precaution foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (!empty($temp)) {
          list($key) = explode("-",$key);
          if ($key == 'sbrands'){
            array_push($brands,$value);
          }
          if (!in_array($key,$getters)){
            $getters[$key] = intval(trim($value));
          }
        }
      }

Comment: I dont get sql warning message anymore while taping ' what I should add to prevent the sql injection mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$value); ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple way you can use if else condition for sort query only. According to your condition like this.

```
$sql = "Rest of the Query..";
if($_GET['order'] == 'price') {
   $sql .= " ORDER BY Price DESC";
} else {
   $sql .= " ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
}
```

When user click Sort by Price or Datetime then query will executed as per the condition.

(Or)

You can update query case condition like below example.

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN "price" = $_GET['order'] THEN price END DESC,
CASE WHEN "datetime" = $_GET['order'] THEN datetime END DESC

(or)

ORDER BY 
CASE $_GET['order'] 
WHEN "price" THEN price END DESC,
WHEN "datetime" THEN datetime END DESC

etc...
```

Whatever you choose booth will be same performance and efficiency.

Comment: THANK YOU Ram I will try this too

Answer (score 1):

You already have this clause:

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
```

All you need, is to add ordering parameter to your query, say `$_GET['order']` as integer index(1-based) in your whitelist orders where sign points to order direction.

```
$orders = ['Datetime', 'Price'];

if (empty($_GET['order'])) $_GET['order'] = -1; // set default order

$index = abs($_GET['order'])-1;
$ord = isset($orders[$index]) ? $orders[$index] : $orders[0];
$direction = $_GET['order'] > 0 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

$sql .= " ORDER BY {$ord} {$direction}";
```

Comment: now to get the records ordred with the current search list i will add the php tag to the link 127.0.0.1/products/?search=<?php ...?>&scategory=<?php ...?>&order=value ?

Comment: i will do this tomorrow thank you for your help vp_arth have a wonderful night